# Is there anything in Python similar to AssemblyInitialize in C#

Tags: python, c#, testing, pytest

I am new to Python Test Framework. Is there any concept in Python Testing, similar to AssemblyInitialize
concept in c#.  I need to run two methods, before every test method runs. I'm aware of setup and teardown methods. I'm looking specifically something similar to AssemblyInitialize in c#.

Thank you.

I googled over the internet to look for anything similar to AssemblyInitialize in C#. Nothing popped up.

Comment: A session-scoped [fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/explanation/fixtures.html)?

Comment: Not fixture. I need to run methods, which are independent of class. Where as in fixture, we can set the variables, in my understanding.

Comment: You can do what you want in a fixture. A session scoped fixture is executed before all tests run (and the part after the yield after all tests are run). If you can set it to `autouse=True` you don't need to reference it anywhere. Check the documentation that I linked above.

Comment: Yeah, fixture worked in this case. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Because a python module is loaded only once, you can simply do like this, although it's an undocumented method.

```
# test_xxx.py

def init_test()
    # Do whatever you want.
    pass
init_test()
```

A documented method is to use `fixture()` like this.

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def init_test():
    # Do whatever you want.
    pass
```